# Right characters from hive string

Tags: hadoop, hiveql

In hive there are no commands for getting the Left and Right part of a string.

For Left it is not hard to find a workaround:

```
SELECT SUBSTR('abcdefgh',1,2);
ab
```

What is the most elegant way to extract the two right hand side characters of the string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently it is possible to use negative numbers inside SUBSTR, as such you can get the relevant substring as follows:

```
SELECT SUBSTR('abcdefgh',-2,2);
gh
```